# Replace invalid filename chars

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to write a small utility function that replaces any sequence of forbidden chars in filename by a dash

For example :

- `foo.txt` ==> `foo.txt`
- `Some string \o/` ==> `Some string -o-`
- `https://stackoverflow.com/questions` ==> `https-stackoverflow.com-questions`

I write the function like this:

```
function Get-SafeFileName{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object]$Data
    )
    process {
    
        $pattern = "[" + [regex]::Escape([string][System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()) +"]+"

        [regex]::Replace($Data, $pattern, "-")
    }
}
```

This is working, except the space character is replaced even it's an allowed character.

`This is a string` results in `This-is-a-string` which isn't necessary.

How to fix that?

Digging a bit shows that `[System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()` doesn't contains the space char (ascii code 32). But there are many other "space" alike chars.

Maybe the regex engine doesn't see the difference?

Comment: You should never use `[regex]::Escape` to escape chars that go to a character class.

Comment: Could you look at it the other way and have an array of allowed chars and if not a match replace with "-"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I don't get you

Comment: @DuchyWare: the regex is convenient because of the quantifiers. Especially, my regex has a leader `+` that replave actually a sequence of forbidden chars to a single dash (like the `://` in the url sample)

Comment: @SteveB Ah yes I missed that requirement.

Comment: See [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67884741/3832970). [`Regex.Escape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-5.0) is not meant to be used to escape chars inside character classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you convert the list of invalid chars incorrectly by casting it to a string, that is where the spaces appear in the character class.

Second, you can't use `Regex.Escape` to escape chars that go to a character class as it is meant to escape the characters that must be literal *outside* a character class.

The fix is

```
function Get-SafeFileName{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object]$Data
    )
    process {
    
        $pattern = '[' + ([System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join '').Replace('\','\\') + ']+'

        [regex]::Replace($Data, $pattern, "-")
    }
}
```

The only characters that need to be escaped inside a character class are:

- `^`
- `-`
- `\`
- `]`.

Since the `GetInvalidFileNameChars()` only contains one of the four special chars mentioned, you can just use a single `.Replace('\', '\\')` instead of all four `.Replace('\','\\') .Replace('-','\-').Replace('^','\^').Replace(']','\]')`.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way using unicode construction

```
function Get-SafeFileName{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object]$Data
    )
    process {
    
        $pattern = "[" + ( ([System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() | % { "\x" + ([int]$_).ToString('X2') } ) -join '') +"]+"

        [regex]::Replace($Data, $pattern, "-")
    }
}
```

`$pattern` is now `[\x22\x3C\x3E\x7C\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0A\x0B\x0C\x0D\x0E\x0F\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1A\x1B\x1C\x1D\x1E\x1F\x3A\x2A\x3F\x5C\x2F]+`

With that, there's no ambiguity. Standard spaces aren't replaced